Help sorting out a typo; outer-measure induced by $\rho((a,b))=(b-a)^2$ is zero.
I was wondering if anybody can help me figure out what the following exercise is supposed to say, because as it's stated I'm nearly certain this is wrong.
Let $\mathcal{E}$ be the set of all open intervals on $\mathbb{R}$. Define $\rho((a,b))=(b-a)^2$. Let $\mu^*$ be the outer measure induced by $\rho$. Prove that $\mu^*=0$.
When the exercise refers to the outer measure induced by $\rho$, I believe it is referring to proposition 1.10 from Folland (which I'm pretty sure also has a typo).
The proposition (with the typo) is stated as:
Let $\mathcal{E}\subset \mathcal{P}(X)$, and $\rho: \mathcal{E}\to[0,\infty]$ be such that $\emptyset \in \mathcal{E}$ and $X\in\mathcal{E}$. For any $A\subset X$, define
$$\mu^*(A)=\inf\Bigg\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty\mu\left(E_j\right): E_j\in\mathcal{E} \text{ and } A\subset\bigcup_{1}^\infty E_j\Bigg\}.$$
Then $\mu^*$ is an outer measure.
I think the typo in the statement of prop 1.10 is in the scope over which the infimum is taken. I believe $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\mu\left(E_j\right)$ is supposed to say $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\rho\left(E_j\right)$, but I don't see that in any of the errata I could find.
Regarding the exercise, the statement seems false to me, since I can just take $A=(0,1)$, then $\mu^*((0,1)) = (1-0)^2=1.$
Can anyone tell what the correct result is supposed to be? Or if I'm the one who's wrong and the result is actually correct?
Thanks so much.

Shouldn't $j$ be $n$ (or vice versa)?

In your example, how do you know that $1$ is the infimum of all such sums?

@Randall Proof by lack of creativity. I'm honestly just struggling to come up with an example, and it feels very false since the usual lebesgue measure isn't horribly different from this one.

Also, yes you are correct about $j$ and $n$. I've edited my post appropriately

Actually I think I'm starting to get an intuition for this. Eg, if I take the interval $(0,1)$ and cover it with $(0,1/2)\cup(1/2,1)$ (not sweating the end points right now), then $\rho(0,1/2)+\rho(1/2,1) = 1/2$. So I guess there's something going on with how the squared length of an interval shrinks it faster than the sum grows.

exactly right!...

For any integer $k$ and a positive integer $n_k$ we have $$ [k,k+1]\subset \bigcup_{j=0}^{n_k}(k+{j-1\over n_k},k+{j+1\over n_k})$$ Hence $$\mathbb{R}\subset \bigcup_{k=-\infty}^\infty  \bigcup_{j=0}^{n_k}(k+{j-1\over n_k},k+{j+1\over n_k}) $$ Thus $$\mu^*(\mathbb{R})\le \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^{n_k}{4\over n_k^2}=4\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty{n_k+1\over n_k^2}\\ \le 8\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty{1\over n_k}$$ For a fixed natural number $m$ let $n_k=m2^{|k|}$ Then $$ 8\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty{1\over n_k}={8\over m} 
 \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty{1\over 2^{|k|}}={24\over m}$$ As $m$ is arbitrary we get $\mu^*(\mathbb{R})=0.$

Thank you so much for giving such a detailed answer!
